# Complex logarithm problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that
$$Log((1+i)^2) = 2Log(1+i),$$
while
$$Log((-1+i)^2) \not= 2Log(-1+i)$$

**Solution:**

I am using $[0 , 2\pi]$ for the principle argument.

The first part worked out fine, I got:

$Log((1+i)^2) = log(2) + i \frac{\pi}{2}$

$2Log(1+i)= log(2) + i \frac{\pi}{2}$

But the second part is not working out because I found that the results *are* equal:

$Log((-1+i)^2) = log(2) + i \frac{3\pi}{2}$

$2Log((-1+i) = log(2) + i \frac{3\pi}{2}$

Comment: Is that a typo for the second case? Note that the left hand side is supposed to be $2\operatorname{Log}(-1+i)$, not $2\operatorname{Log}(1+i)$.

Are you sure you're supposed to use $[0,2\pi]$ for the principal argument? (It's usually $[-\pi, \pi]$.)

Comment: There is a typo, but if you use $[0,2\pi]$, then the results _are_ going to be the same, since you don't cross the branch cut, when you square. You are probably supposed to use the branch $\theta\in [-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Actually, neither $[0,2\pi]$ nor $[-\pi,\pi]$ make sense as defining a branch for the logarithm. However $[0,2\pi)$ and $(-\pi,\pi]$ do (and the latter even makes the exercise solvable).

Comment: Many have noted that this problem might have a typo, and was meant to use $[0,2\pi)$ for the principle argument range. It is also possible that the second equation was meant to involve $-1-i$  or $1-i$ rather than $-1+i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using $[0,2\pi)$ as the range of the principal argument, then the results in the second part *are* indeed equal.

The exercise is probably meant to be solved with the principal argument having the range $(-\pi,\pi]$ -- which is somewhat more common, because it behaves nicer near the positive real axis. With that choice of principal argument you should get $\operatorname{Log}(-1+i)= \frac12\log2 + \frac34 \pi i$ but
$\operatorname{Log}((-1+i)^2) = \log2 - \frac12\pi i$.